# How to properly check if std::function is empty in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I was wondering how to properly check if an `std::function` is empty. Consider this example:

```
class Test {
    std::function<void(int a)> eventFunc;

    void registerEvent(std::function<void(int a)> e) {
        eventFunc = e;
    }

    void doSomething() {
        ...
        eventFunc(42);
    }
};
```

This code compiles just fine in MSVC but if I call `doSomething()` without initializing the `eventFunc` the code obviously crashes. That's expected but I was wondering what is the value of the `eventFunc`? The debugger says `'empty'`. So I fixed that using simple if statement:

```
   void doSomething() {
        ...
        if (eventFunc) {
            eventFunc(42);
        }
   }
```

This works but I am still wondering what is the value of non-initialized `std::function`? I would like to write `if (eventFunc != nullptr)` but `std::function` is (obviously) not a pointer.

Why the pure if works? What's the magic behind it? And, is it the correct way how to check it?

Comment: Note that `eventFunc` isn't a lambda; it's a `std::function`. You can store lambdas in `std::function`s, but they're not the same thing.

Comment: You are right, I changed the title to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You're not checking for an empty lambda, but whether the [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) has a callable target stored in it. The check is well-defined and works because of [`std::function::operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool) which allows for implicit conversion to `bool` in contexts where boolean values are required (such as the conditional expression in an `if` statement).

Besides, the notion of an *empty lambda* doesn't really make sense. Behind the scenes the compiler converts a lambda expression into a `struct` (or `class`) definition, with the variables you capture stored as data members of this `struct`. A public function call operator is also defined, which is what allows you to invoke the lambda. So what would an empty lambda be?

---

You can also write `if(eventFunc != nullptr)` if you wish to, it's equivalent to the code you have in the question. `std::function` [defines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_cmp) `operator==` and `operator!=` overloads for comparing with a `nullptr_t`.

Comment: Doesn't `== nullptr` do the same thing, though? It looks like there's supposed to be an overload for the `==` operator that causes an "empty" `std::function` to compare `true` against `nullptr`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/operators/

Comment: @KyleStrand Yes, comparing to `nullptr` will work too, `if(eventFunc != nullptr)` is equivalent to `if(eventFunc)` in the question above.

Comment: Technically, `std::function::operator bool` does not allow implicit conversion to `bool`.  It is marked `explicit` after all, but the standard makes an exception for certain language constructs that expect boolean expressions, calling it "contextually converted to bool."  You can find the relevant snippet of standardese and an explanation here: http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.com/2013/07/contextually-converted-to-bool.html

Comment: @bcrist Yep, I'm aware that the boolean conversion operator is `explicit`, that's why i was careful to state *allows for implicit conversion to `bool` in contexts where boolean values are required*. This is exactly what's happening in the code in question.

Comment: @Praetorian The point I'm trying to make is that the standard assigns a very specific meaning to the phrase "implicit conversion", and it is distinctly different from "contextual conversion to bool," which also has a very specific meaning.  There is no "Is-a" relationship here.  I understand that beginners probably don't need to know the difference between implicit/explicit/contextual conversion right away, but it's better to learn the right words subconsciously, than have to break old habits later.

Answer (score 38):

Check here for [std::function::operator bool](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/operator_bool/)

#### Return value

- true if the object is callable.
- false otherwise (the object is an empty function).

---

**Example**:

```
// function::operator bool example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <functional>   // std::function, std::plus

int main ()
{
    std::function<int(int,int)> foo; // empty
    
    if(foo)
    {
        std::cout << "[1] foo is NOT empty" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "[1] foo is EMPTY" << std::endl;
    }
    
    // Now we can assign example
    foo = std::plus<int>();
  
    if(foo)
    {
        std::cout << "[2] foo is NOT empty" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "[2] foo is EMPTY" << std::endl;
    }
  
    // Example use with ternary operator (https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html)
    std::cout << "[3] foo is " << (foo ? "callable" : "NOT callable") << std::endl;
    
    // make it empty
    foo = {};
    std::cout << "[4] foo is " << (foo ? "callable" : "NOT callable") << std::endl;
    
    foo = [](int a, int b){ return a+b; };
    std::cout << "[5] foo is " << (foo ? "callable" : "NOT callable") << std::endl;
    
    return foo(1, 1) == 2; // return 1
}
```

---

**Output**

```
[1] foo is EMPTY
[2] foo is NOT empty
[3] foo is callable
[4] foo is NOT callable
[5] foo is callable
```

Comment: I think this answer would be more clear without the `swap()`. I was thinking the output was backwards until I realized it.

Comment: Isn't [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) much much better than [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com)? I really find the former examples much more clear. Why so many people turned to latter? I wonder!

Comment: @Vassilis cplusplus did not have documentation for newer C++ standards for a long time. cppreference is up-to-date and have formal definitions. I suggest using cplusplus at learning phase.

Answer (score 7):

(Let me provide a clear answer.)

You can check if a `std::function` is empty with [`std::function::operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool).

> true: if the object is callable.
>   false: otherwise (the object is an empty function)

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main ()
{
    std::function<int(int,int)> foo = std::plus<int>();//assigned: not empty
    std::function<int(int,int)> bar;//not assigned: empty

    std::cout << "foo is " << (foo ? "not empty" : "empty") << ".\n";
    std::cout << "bar is " << (bar ? "not empty" : "empty") << ".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> foo is not empty.
>   bar is empty.

Comment: Your result strings are swapped.

Comment: Your comment says foo is not empty and the output disagrees. I agree with your comment.